# ¿Cómo traer desde una sola session más datos?

Tags: php, session

Tengo un formulario de un solo campo donde se ingresa un código de trabajador.

```
<form id="tck" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="ticket" maxlength="10">
 <button type="submit">ticket</button>
</form>
```

Estos datos se envían a través de `AJAX`, la petición se realiza desde la página principal **Index.php**

Los valores que se reciben desde la petición de `AJAX` **employee.php**

```
$ticket = $_POST['ticket'] ?: '';
$stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT ... FROM employee WHERE workercode=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$ticket);

#code...

else {
  $_SESSION['ticket'] = $salary;
}
```

Se debe tener en cuenta que las siguientes variables se obtiene valores desde una consulta preparada, la misma que se encuentra en el archivo employee.php.

```
$salary //sueldo del trabajador
$workercode //código del trabajador
```

En la página **index.php** tengo lo siguiente:

```
session_start();
$codeticket = (isset($_SESSION['ticket']));
echo $_SESSION['ticket'];
```

Cómo resultado obtengo satisfactoriamente el sueldo:

**430**

Pero también necesito obtener el código del trabajador.

He intentado reemplazar esto:

```
else {
  $_SESSION['ticket'] = $salary;
}
```

por esto:

```
else {
  //$_SESSION['ticket'] + $salary + $workercode;
  //$_SESSION['ticket'] = $salary && $_SESSION['ticket'] = $workercode;
}
```

Pero sigo sin poder obtener los dos datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurren 2 soluciones a tu problema:

### Opción 1

Convertir `$_SESSION['ticket']` en un arreglo asociativo para almacenar mas datos.

*employee.php*

```
// ...
} else {
    $_SESSION['ticket'] = array(
        'salary' => $salary,
        'workercode' => $workercode,
    );
}
```

*index.php*

```
session_start();
$codeticket = isset($_SESSION['ticket']);
echo $_SESSION['ticket']['salary'];
echo $_SESSION['ticket']['workercode'];
```

---

### Opción 2

Crear mas variables de `$_SESSION`.

*employee.php*

```
  // ...
} else {
    $_SESSION['salary'] = $salary;
    $_SESSION['workercode'] = $workercode;
}
```

*index.php*

```
session_start();
$codeticket = isset($_SESSION['salary']);
echo $_SESSION['salary'];
echo $_SESSION['workercode'];
```

Comment: Excelente no ha sido tan complicado, gracias :)